# Cart and Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, next.js13

I am building an application using nrxtjs 13 and react . In it have 3 components cart, button,counter so when user clicks on button quantity value onclick should appear in cart which is a comonent of navbar
So this is button under the code i will explain issue

```
"use client";
import {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  createContext,
} from "react";
import { CgShoppingCart } from "react-icons/cg";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

export const Context = createContext({
  quantity: 0,
  // setQuantity: (): number => 0,
});

const Button = ({
  quantity,
  price,
  product_id,
}: {
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
  product_id: string;
}) => {
  const initialButtonClassName =
    "flex bg-[#212121] text-white justify-center items-center px-4 py-2 border-t-2 border-t-[#545454] border-l-2 border-l-[#545454] border-r-2 border-r-black border-b-2 border-b-black";
  const activeButtonClassName =
    "flex bg-[#212121] text-white justify-center items-center px-4 py-2 border-t-2 border-t-black border-l-2 border-l-black border-r-2 border-r-[#545454] border-b-2 border-b-[#545454]";
  const [buttonClassName, setButtonClassName] = useState(
    initialButtonClassName
  );
  const sendData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/cart", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          quantity,
          price,
          product_id,
        }),
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        toast.success("Successfully added product to your cart. Enjoy");
        return await response.json();
      } else {
        toast.error("Sorry something went wrong");
        return await response.json();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred while adding product to cart:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonClassName(activeButtonClassName);
    sendData();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buttonClassName === activeButtonClassName) {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setButtonClassName(initialButtonClassName);
      }, 100);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [buttonClassName, initialButtonClassName, activeButtonClassName]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ quantity }}>
      <button className={buttonClassName} onClick={handleClick}>
        <Toaster />
        <CgShoppingCart style={{ fontSize: "24px", color: "white" }} />
        Add to Cart
      </button>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

the createContext(0) default value is 0 i am doing this to share quantity value  <Context.Provider value={{ quantity }}> to my cart component its code is

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { CgShoppingCart } from "react-icons/cg";
import { Context } from "../counter/button";

export default function Cart() {
  const { quantity } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <div className="flex w-12 h-12 relative rounded-full items-center justify-center bg-[#F1F1F1] hover:transform hover:transition-transform hover:duration-400 hover:ease-in-out">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-4 h-4 absolute rounded-full bg-red-500 text-white right-1 top-0">
        {quantity}
      </div>
      <CgShoppingCart style={{ fontSize: "24px" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

ow the problem is that when i click on button the cart value dont change to value of quantity but remains 0 if i use useState hook than also it dont work i want to know how can i change the value that cart recieves to quantity as this value={{ quantity }} not doing anything.

Sorrry its long but i need your help

I tried differnt methods like use hooks to change the value of Context but nothing worked as default value is set to 0 if i change it to 10 at createContext(10) than it changes but value={{quantity}} is not so i want to dynamically change the value of cart if the quantity changes as the quantity changes cart value changes and if click button then also it changes

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I thought it was a problem with "use client" but then it becomes clear:

The issue here seems to be that **each instance of your Button** component is creating **a new context with the quantity** value as that particular instance's quantity. *This means each Button is creating and providing its own context, which is isolated from the other instances of Button.*

To share state across multiple components, you need to lift the state up to a common ancestor of all components that need access to that state. In this case, it might be helpful to create a **CartProvider** component that provides the cart context to all child components, like Button and Cart. You can create the context just once in this CartProvider. Then you must wrap your app (or the common ancestor of Button and Cart) in CartProvider.

```
export const CartContext = createContext({
  quantity: 0,
  addToCart: (q) => {},
});

export function CartProvider({children}) {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  
  const addToCart = (q) => {
    setQuantity(prevQuantity => prevQuantity + q);
  };
  
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ quantity, addToCart }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You can use any Provider like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      {/* your other awesome components */}
      <Button /* props */ />
      <Cart />
      {/* these button and cart components don't have to be placed here. They can reach the context in anywhere. Because the whole project is wrapped by CartProvider */}
    </CartProvider>
  );
}
```

After all, you use Context inside button component;

```
  const { quantity, addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
```

Just add that line inside your Button component. It will fetch the quantity and addToCart from CartContext.

This approach is also fine as it seperates the ui and logic. I am big fan of this. Even you don't need a context, you may create custom hooks to get and handle data like as we do now. It will decrease the code lines of your components. You'll be able to rule the data efficiently.

**Note:** According to me, as Redux toolkit is really easy to understand, you may think using it. It also wraps the whole app so that you can react the state in any component.

**Redux Toolkit Example on Codesandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-list-with-react-7ptxdf?file=/src/components/todoList/todoListSlice.js

Comment: Hi , first of all thanks for answering second from your code and explanation it concludes that we should have an cartProvider that provides the state and than use this CartProvider to share state throughtout components and use counter component to increment or decrement the state value and when you do the state state will change throughout the application